# Does anyone know how to get the IMEI number of device in React Native using EXPO?

Tags: react-native, react-native-device-info

How can I get Device IMEI number in React Native using EXPO?

Previously I was using **react-native-imei** to get IMEI Numbers of device *when the App was created using react-native*.

Now we are having another app which is created using EXPO - it will be helpful if anyone can guide how to get the IMEI number of a device using EXPO.

Comment: do you find any solution regarding imei in expo?

Comment: Do you find any solution?